Why is the defaultRequest of a LimitRange not applied to a pod that specifies only the limit?
I was learning about LimitRanges when on this page I encountered a scenario where you have a LimitRange with a specified defaultRequest in place. Then, a pod specification only specifies a limit (and not a request). If you schedule this pod, it gets its request set to its limit, instead of the defaultRequest specified in the LimitRange. The documentation is clear about this:

The output shows that the container's memory request is set to match its memory limit. Notice that the container was not assigned the default memory request value of 256Mi.

However, I'm having a hard time understanding why this happens, and the wiki doesn't really touch specifically. I expected the defaultRequest to be applied. If I omit both the limit and a range from my pod specification, then the defaultRequest values are applied.
Am I missing something on the conceptual level that might explain why the defaultRequest values aren't used if only the limit is specified in a pod spec? Any help would be appreciated!
